# how to make windows act like iperf -w

Tags: networking, tcp, iperf

I have 2 clients with a long distance 10 Gbit fibre connection between them.  When i run iperf3 -c x.x.x.x -w 3m on the client, i manage to get close to the full 10 Gbit throughput.

When i on the other hand just use iper3 -c x.x.x.x (so not specifying window size) i only get about 1 Gbit.  So now i'm wondering how to make my client use the 3m window size by default ?

The client i use is a windows server 2012 r2. I've enabled autoscaling

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> netsh int tcp show heuristics
TCP Window Scaling heuristics Parameters
----------------------------------------------
Window Scaling heuristics         : disabled
Qualifying Destination Threshold  : 3
Profile type unknown              : normal
Profile type public               : normal
Profile type private              : normal
Profile type domain               : normal

PS C:\Users\Administrator> netsh int tcp show global
Querying active state...

TCP Global Parameters
----------------------------------------------
Receive-Side Scaling State          : enabled
Chimney Offload State               : disabled
NetDMA State                        : disabled
Direct Cache Access (DCA)           : disabled
Receive Window Auto-Tuning Level    : normal
Add-On Congestion Control Provider  : none
ECN Capability                      : enabled
RFC 1323 Timestamps                 : disabled
Initial RTO                         : 3000
Receive Segment Coalescing State    : enabled
Non Sack Rtt Resiliency             : disabled
Max SYN Retransmissions             : 2
```

The server is an ubuntu 14.04. 
I've used sysctl to set following parameters :

```
net.core.wmem_max=12582912
net.core.rmem_max=12582912
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem=10240 87380 12582912
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem=10240 87380 12582912
```